# Deleted /etc/, can't boot from DVD

Tags: snow-leopard, imac, dvd

I accidentally deleted the files in `/etc/` (yes into /private/etc) and my iMac gets stuck on a blue screen after the initial apple logo now. I tried to boot from install DVD but it hangs at the apple logo when I do that.

Any suggestions on how to fix or reinstall the OS?

This is an iMac with OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

See [Startup key combinations for Intel-based Macs (HT1533)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533) for a list of available key combinations during startup. In your case you should use either of

- <kbd>C</kbd>: Start up from a bootable CD, DVD, or USB thumb drive (such as OS X install media)
- <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>: Start up in Startup Manager, where you can select an OS X volume to start from. In your case the volume to select is the OS X Snow Leopard DVD

Comment: mentioned that i tried booting from DVD already, hangs at apple logo. The only non-regular mode I can boot into is single-user root mode.

Answer (score 1):

My iMac would loose its boot sequence because I had it booting into Windows mode. What Apple told me to do was to hold down the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key while the machine was rebooting.